# Trouble using Charts Framework in an iOS App project with Swift Package manager

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-charts

I added the Charts framework (from Danielgindi) to my iOS xcode project using the Swift Package Manager. This installed correctly and the dependency appears to be correct in the config screens. But when I try to add the library to the ViewController.swift file in my empty project with "import Charts" but I get Xcode build error "no such module Charts"

I don't believe this is an issue with my xcode config as I have successfully added other swift packages in exactly the same way and then was able to import their libraries without error.  Has anyone else encountered this?

Charts Environment
Charts version/Branch/Commit Number: 3.6 (I think whatever latest is)
Xcode version: Version 12.2 (12B45b)
Swift version: 5.2 
Xcode: 11.1

Comment: I had the same issue about 4 months ago, I resolved the issue by `Reset Package Cache` and updating all my packages to their latest versions. I also had to remove the pod that was installed for `Charts` it was causing a conflict in my Build Phase

Comment: Usually I solve it by pressing this combination ```cmd + Shift + k``` and rebuilding the project.

Comment: Thanks for both of these suggestions. Unfortunately neither work.  I will probably revert to using the pod version - I was just hoping to have the simplicity of the SPM version

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem and spent the last few hours figuring out a solution so I can start using charts with SPM :-)

First of all, it looks like there are some errors in the current master branch of Charts. There are a few pull requests to fix the issue, here's the one that worked for me. https://github.com/ArthurValiev/Charts/tree/bugfix/spm_build_fix
Based on issue [#4550](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/pull/4550)

In Xcode I added https://github.com/ArthurValiev/Charts.git to the SPM dialog
and typed in branch bugfix/spm_build_fix instead of master and only checked Charts (not DynamicCharts). I then was able to build the project and Import Charts.

This seems to be a temporary solution until the fix is merged into the latest build or master branch.

UPDATE ... This fix has been added the latest master branch. I've successfully imported Charts and built using SPM and master branch.
https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/commit/30cd352013d489ea49fd605dd2c0f3d6c685d0a5

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain your fix.  This sounds like a great work around!

Comment: I did try this but seem to have the same problem.  Xcode can't find the library name after import.  I think I'll just revert to pod version.

Comment: Xcode will show that it can't find the library name until you build the project, mine did the same thing. Once I did the steps above, I then ran the project to build all everything and the red underline disappeared.

Comment: Can this ever be put in plain English? I have no freaking idea how to change my podfile to point to this forked version of Charts.